# How to create a local distributed database using multiple laptops or virtual machines?

Tags: database, relational-database, distributed-computing, distributed-system, distributed-database

I want to run an academic experiment and need to create a distributed database. My plan is to use four devices: two of them running the database, one running a load balancer algorithms and the other sending requests. **How do I create this local distributed database system using multiple laptops or virtual machines?**

I'm currently using macOS; however, windows works too.

MYSQL or Postgres is favourable. Otherwise, any technology is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not repost questions. Edit them. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55394882/3404097 From the posting times it seems like you might have accidentally reposted while editing? PS This question is too broad. [ask]

Comment: https://severalnines.com/blog/postgresql-load-balancing-using-haproxy-keepalived

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://blog.marceloaltmann.com/proxysql-tutorial-master-and-slave/

ProxySQL is a loadbalancer for MySQL. I've used it in the past and it should serve you well.